# Having trouble getting my output to show up in my terminal while using methods

Tags: java

Having a problem with dealing with methods. It is a simple program, but I just can't seem to get my data to print to the terminal

Here's my code:

```
public class method
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        double result = 0;
        int i;
        System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" +  "m(i)");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        //columns and header

    }
    public double theSum(int i, double result)
    {
        for(i=0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i + "\t\t" + result + "\n");
            result +=(double) (i + 1)/(i+2);   
            // computing the data
        }
        return result;
    }    
}
```

Everything compiles, but my output only prints my headers... I think my bottom method may be wrong, but not sure where.

```
Sample output:
1        0.5
2        1.16
...
19       16.40
20       17.35
```

Comment: Are you calling your method? Or do you expect it will call itself? Java only does what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the method to print your output

```
    public static void main( String args[] )
        {     
           double result = 0;
            int i=0;
            System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" +  "m(i)");
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            //columns and header
           method d=new method();
            d.theSum(i,result);

}
```

**output**

```
i       m(i)
-------------------
0       0.0
1       0.5
2       1.1666666666666665
3       1.9166666666666665
4       2.716666666666667
5       3.5500000000000003
6       4.4071428571428575
```

Comment: ok thank you. Are there alternate ways to print to the output. I ask that because I have never seen method d=new method();
        d.theSum(i,result);

Comment: you need to create the class object to call the instance method.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called your method at all.

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    double result = 0;
    int i;
    System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" +  "m(i)");
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    //columns and header
    double result = theSum(5,result); //Call the method
}
```

Also why do you need to pass the variable **i**? You are resetting it to zero inside the loop.